# Visual Studio + Unity Ошибка CS0103

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

При использовании Visual Studio после переноса проекта на другой компьютер(версии Unity одинаковы) большое количество ошибок CS0103 в каждом скрипте , хотя на другом пк они отсутствуют, Visual Studio установлена с Unity Hub.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А резервные копии делаете? Откройте резервную копию, и посмотрите по F12, где он этот transform находится.

Comment: @aepot этот `transform` находится в `unity3d`, как и `gameObject` с методом `Destroy()`. Все это относится к `MonoBehaviour`.